# Strange behaviour TableView cell after clicking on AdMob smart banner

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, admob

I have some strange behaviour inside a tableview **after clicking** on an AdMob smart banner. It adds an offset (black bar) below the cell, on top or the whole cell even appears overlapping on top of other custom cells inside the table view **after scrolling** all the way to the top of the tableview and back again.

Prerequisites:

- Custom cell
- Registered Nib
- Inside TableView
- AdMob (latest version)
- Only after clicking on interactive banner (It's not a banner with a static image that only requires one click)
- No problems with other custom cells that have clickable content

Attachment (including the black bar that seems to separate the two custom cells)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to an other custom cell that was dynamically changing it's own height.